# Cake PHP 2 query count different between model and raw SQL

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm working inside a legacy Cake PHP 2.10 project and need to get all rows from my `Application` model joining a few tables. When I perform the same query using Cake's query builder compared to raw SQL, the number of records returned over the same period of time is different, not by a few, but by several thousand. The accurate one is the raw SQL version and I'm trying to understand why the query builder version is returning less results, what could I be missing?

```php
/**
 * Get consolidated report
 */
public function getReport($report = 'full')
{
    $this->Application = ClassRegistry::init('Application');

    $applications = $this->Application->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Application.*',
            'ApplicationPayday.*',
            'Commission.*',
            'ApplicationResponse.*'
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Application.modified_timestamp >=' => $this->getStartDate(),
            'Application.modified_timestamp <=' => $this->getEndDate()
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'application_responses',
                'alias' => 'ApplicationResponse',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'ApplicationResponse.application_id = Application.id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'application_paydays',
                'alias' => 'ApplicationPayday',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'ApplicationPayday.application_id = Application.id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'commissions',
                'alias' => 'Commission',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Commission.application_response_id = ApplicationResponse.id'
                )
            )
        ),
        'recursive' => -1
    ));

    /* Query to Execute */
  $sql = "SELECT
          payday.BankAccount,
          payday.EmpIncomeType,
          application.tlp_aff_id,
          application.modified_timestamp
          FROM
          tlp_applications application
          LEFT JOIN tlp_application_responses response ON response.application_id = application.id
          LEFT JOIN tlp_application_paydays payday ON application.id = payday.application_id
          LEFT JOIN tlp_commissions commissions ON commissions.application_response_id = response.id
          WHERE
          (application.modified_timestamp BETWEEN '" . $this->getStartDate() . "' AND '" . $this->getEndDate() . "')";

    /* Execute Query */
    $submits = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->fetchAll($sql);


    echo "count query builder: " . count($applications) . ' <br />'; // outputs 9768
    echo "count raw sql: " . count($submits) . ' <br />'; // outputs 23904
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can investigate the Cake generate `$applications`  SQL code.

Here is how you can print the last query in your Model. https://www.knowband.com/blog/tips/print-last-executed-query-cakephp2/

Comment: I'd guess it's the conditions it could performing an `OR` operator instead of `AND`.